# Is the companion iPhone app mandatory for Apple Watch apps?

Tags: ios, development, apple-watch, watchos

I am developing a simple standalone app for the Apple Watch. I really don't need any functionality on the phone. Am I required to provide an iPhone app?

The watchkit documentation is something like:

> Create WatchKit apps. WatchKit apps have two parts: A WatchKit
>   extension that runs on iPhone and a set of user interface resources
>   that are installed on Apple Watch. When your app is launched on Apple
>   Watch, the WatchKit extension on iPhone runs in the background to
>   update the user interface and respond to user interactions. WatchKit
>   provides three opportunities to extend your iPhone app to Apple Watch:
>   WatchKit apps, Glances, and actionable notifications.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a corresponding iOS app is required. The watchOS component is considered an extension by Apple and not a standalone product.

See [Preparing Your 
App Submission for Apple Watch](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/submit/):

> ### App Review
>
> All iPhone apps with a WatchKit extension submitted to the App Store are reviewed based on a set of technical, content, and design criteria. Make sure to use our guidelines and resources before submitting your app for review.